# PostAsync is not working when URL contain port

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

My .net application try to access external API by using the code below...

```
using (var keyClient = new HttpClient())
{
    keyClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webshopurl"]);
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_username",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webshopAPIUserName"]),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_password",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webshopAPIPassword"])
    });
    var result = keyClient.PostAsync("/api/v1/key.php", content).Result;
    token = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

When calling from local machine it works properly. But when it is hosted in online server URL such like `http://app.test.net:5000/test` it is not calling to the API. If we host such a URL like `http://app.test.net/test` it is working properly.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What error message if any do you get/log when on the remote server. Start looking there for clues as to why it is not calling the API.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `.Result` to unpack the result? It's a lot better to use `await` to get the result from an `async` method.
`.Result` can cause a deadlock if you are not being careful with the context.

Stephen Cleary has a really nice articles that goes into more details.

[Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: This looks more like a comment than as an answer.